# Swift UIImagePickerController problem with photo in iCloud and allowsEditing

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, icloud

I need help.
I use UIImagePickerController to load the avatar. I can take a picture from camera and you can choose a photo.
I have photos stored partly in iCloud, and only previews on the device, partly locally.
When choosing a local photo or from camera, we get to the area selection screen, image cropping.
So if the photo is stored in iCloud, then the following happens:

I select a photo, click done - the window closes, but there is no photo.

My code:

Code for choose photo from library

```
func openMediaDialog() {
    
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
                        //self.imagePicker.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)
                        //If you dont want to edit the photo then you can set allowsEditing to false
                        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
                        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    
                } else if status == .denied {
                
                    self.alertCameraAccessNeeded(title: "Необходим доступ к фото!", message: "Для загрузки аватара необходим доступ к фото. Разрешить?")
                }
        })
    
    
}
```

DELEGATE:

```
override func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    /*
     Get the image from the info dictionary.
     If no need to edit the photo, use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`
     instead of `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`
     */
    
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        self.view.makeToast("Проблема с выбором изображения")
        
    }
    
    
    
    print(selectedImage)
....
```

NEXT STEP - UPLOAD IMAGE

I ask you to tell me how to make sure that the photos are downloaded from icloud, cropped as needed and loaded further according to the usual scenario to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will get PHAsset if your photos on iCloud.. use this function to get photos

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        // it will be loaded asynchronously
        loadImageFromPicker(info: info)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func loadImageFromPicker(info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let phAsset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset else {
            return
        }
       
        // size doesn't matter, because resizeMode = .none
        let size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        options.resizeMode = .none
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: phAsset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options) { [weak self] (image, info) in
            if let s = self, let image = image {
                // use this image
            }
        }
    }
```